# Linq To Sql - Changing Sort Order At Run-Time with well known static typing

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sorting

This is not another question about 'How Can I Sort Dynamically (based on an arbitrary user provided field)?'

The question is -- how can I change sort order when I know the potential sorts in advance? (And thus avoid reflection / custom Expression building typically associated with truly dynamic sorting.)

Take for instance this subquery (shortened for this example) of a larger query:

```
(from solutionIds in context.csExtendedQAIncident_Docs
    where solutionIds.tiRecordStatus == 1
    && (from solutionProductAssocation in context.csProductDocs
           where solutionProductAssocation.iSiteId == Settings.Current.WebUtility().Onyx.SiteId
           && (from allowedProduct in context.KB_User_Allowed_Products
                  where allowedProduct.UserId == userId
                  select allowedProduct.ModelCode
               ).Contains(solutionProductAssocation.chModelCd)
           select solutionProductAssocation.chIdNo).Distinct().Contains(solutionIds.chIdNo)
).OrderByDescending(s => s.dtUpdateDate)
.Select(s => s.chIdNo)
.Take(count ?? Settings.Current.WCFServices().Output.HomePage.MaxRows)
```

The OrderByDescending portion works as I would expect.

Now -- I want to factor that out like the following:

```
Expression<Func<csExtendedQAIncident_Doc, IComparable>> ordering =  (s) => s.dtUpdateDate;
if (viewType == HomepageViewType.MostViewed)
   ordering = (s) => s.vchUserField8;
else if (viewType == HomepageViewType.MostEffective)
   ordering = (s) => s.vchUserField4;
```

and then use:

```
OrderByDescending(ordering)
```

This does compile, but blows up at run-time.

```
Unsupported overload used for query operator 'OrderByDescending'.
```

This of course comes from deep in the bowels of System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter -- in particular VisitSequenceOperatorCall.  Reflectoring that code reveals that the following conditions must be met for OrderByDescending to properly evaluate.  'mc' is the MethodCallExpression passed into the method.

```
if (((mc.Arguments.Count != 2) || !this.IsLambda(mc.Arguments[1]))
    || (this.GetLambda(mc.Arguments[1]).Parameters.Count != 1))
{
   break;
}
```

So essentially that MethodCallExpression has to have 2 arguments, the second of which has to be a Expressions.LambdaExpression with a single parameter (presumably the sort field).  If that code breaks out, the exception that I got is thrown.

So clearly I have not constructed the expression correctly.  Without digging in any further here, does anyone know how to correctly construct the sorting Expression?

Comment: I tried something like 

OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<csExtendedQAIncident_Doc, IComparable>>(ordering, ordering.Parameters))

But that wasn't quite right either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the unsupported part of your code is the use of `IComparable` as a general return type for your ordering expression. If you consider the plain use of `OrderByDescending`, the compiler-generated lambda expression has a return type of the type of the property that you're ordering by: for example, an `Expression<Func<csExtendedQAIncident_doc, string>>` for a string property.

One possible answer, although I'm not sure whether it works in your case, is to first create an unordered query:

```
IQueryable<Foo> unorderedQuery = from f in db.Foo select f;
```

And then, depending on the sort:

```
IOrderedQueryable<Foo> orderedQuery = unorderedQuery
    .OrderBy(f => f.DefaultSortKey);

if (sortBy == SortByName)
    orderedQuery = unorderedQuery.OrderBy(f => f.Name);
else if (sortBy == SortByDate)
    orderedQuery = unorderedQuery.OrderBy(f => f.Date);
// etc.
```

Comment: Thats actually the approach I want to / intended to use, *if* I could factor the subquery out into a separate query.  So far, my attempts to do that have been unsuccessful.  I've noticed some inconsistencies (probably with my understanding ;0) of Linq to Sql when it comes to breaking down subqueries into chunks for readability purposes -- sometimes it works without a problem, and other times I received unexpected issuess.  I will probably post another question.

At this point, my above question was purely academic until I figure out the subquery issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will not work unless the two possible fields have the *identical* type.

Then the linq to sql will (if possible) correctly create the relevant sql.

so for example if both of those fields were DateTimes:

```
Expression<Func<csExtendedQAIncident_Doc, DateTime>> ordering = 
    s => s.dtUpdateDate;
if (viewType == HomepageViewType.MostViewed)
   ordering = (s) => s.vchUserField8;  // a DateTime
else if (viewType == HomepageViewType.MostEffective)
   ordering = (s) => s.vchUserField4;  // another  DateTime
```

Then this would work just fine (I tested it and it worked)

You could instead do a per type order by either a series of nested switch/if statements of by constructing a dictionary or similar structure to get them.

For the linq to sql to work without explicit dynamic creation of the query I believe it must know the *precise* type of the query as opposed to just it being an IComparable...

Comment: Thanks -- same explanation as Ben from above.  It seems unusual to me to that I couldn't just use a comparable to treat this generically.  File it as a Linq limitation I suppose.

Thanks!